# How to set values for selects programatically in React through refs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

Here is how I can set selects using pure JS. Plain, simple and effective:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">1<option>
    <option value="2">2<option>
</select>

$("#mySelect").value = '1'
```

Not with React. This approach for some reason doesn't work in React. Select values are not updated. Why? How can I do in React?

I have a usual DOM `<form>` with a `[reset]` button. On click `reset` the default browser behavior is to clear all form fields. Why I can't set select after it?

```
onReset(ev) {
    // First I update state. 
    // And AFTER the DOM has been updated, 
    // I want to set selects programatically using refs
    this.setState((state, props) => {
        return {
            birthday: moment(this.props.user.birthday),
            error: null,
            foo: this.props.foo
        }
    }, () => {

        // These both approaches do not work! Why?
        this.country.value = this.props.user.country;
        this.role.value = this.props.user.role;

        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.country).value = this.props.user.country;
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.role).value = this.props.user.role;
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <form action="" onReset={ (ev)=> { this.onReset(ev) } }>

            <select id="country" ref={ node => this.country = node } defaultValue={this.props.user.country}>
                <option value="us">USA<option>
                <option value="ca">Canada<option>
            </select>

            <select id="role" ref={ node => this.role = node } defaultValue={this.props.user.role}>
                <option value="admin">Admin<option>
                <option value="user">User<option>
            </select>

            <botton type={'reset'}>
        </form>
    )
}
```

I know I can do it using controlled components. Please don't advice it because I need to the approach above, I have quite a big form that is rendered slowly when every field is a controlled field.

Here is my original question https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12422

UPD:

[image]

Comment: `$("#mySelect").value = '1'` pure JS or jQuery?

Comment: @TheReason Doesn't matter. It's pseudo code. Actually you can call it in Chrome console without jQuery on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callback is not equal to asynchronous! Actually, you did have changed the value. It just then get reset by browser's reset event handler. Same as the above no-react demo. You can make it work this way:

```
this.setState((state, props) => {
    return {
        birthday: moment(this.props.user.birthday),
        error: null,
        foo: this.props.foo
    }
}, () => {
   // make it asynchronous
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.country.value = this.props.user.country;
      this.role.value = this.props.user.role;
    }, 0)    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not that the value of select options are not changing with refs, but because there is nothing to trigger to DOM update, you aren't able to see the change. You should reset the select value before calling `setState` which shouldn't be a problem since states being set are not dependent on the dropdown state.

```
onReset(ev) {
    // First I update state. 
    // Both reset and DOM update will happen simultaneously with this approach
    this.country.value = this.props.user.country;
    this.role.value = this.props.user.role;

    this.setState((state, props) => {
        return {
            birthday: moment(this.props.user.birthday),
            error: null,
            foo: this.props.foo
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. Selects are being reset to defaults. I actually forgot to mention in my question that I use `defaultValue={}` for selects too. Does it matter for this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm what is the value of this.props.user.country when you try to do onReset

Comment: Yes, please see my screenshot update in question. The value is correct

Comment: well "US" is not the same as "us" and this.props.role.roleId doesn't have any value among admin or user so that why select isn't working

Comment: There is everything correct there. I added a read code screenshot. And shortened code as an example to type here in SO. So values on `<option>` are all uppercase and match values from refs